# Undoing automatic linkification using Java and Regex

Tags: java, regex

I am working with a database whose entries contain automatically generated html links: each URL was converted to

```
 <a href="URL">URL</a>
```

I want to undo these links: the new software will generate the links on the fly. Is there a way in Java to use .replaceAll or a Regex method that will replace the fragments with just the URL (only for those cases where the URLs match)?

To clarify, based on the questions below: the existing entries will contain one or more instances of linkified URLs. Showing an example of just one:

```
I visited <a href="http://www.amazon.com/">http://www.amazon.com/</a> to buy a book.
```

should be replaced with

```
I visited http://www.amazon.com/ to buy a book.
```

If the URL in the href differs in any way from the link text, the replacement should not occur.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking. Could you give some examples of when to replace (and what to replace with) and when not to replace?

Comment: what's the expected result? can you provide some example?

Comment: Do you want to update the database values with an update statement?  I am not following.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern with replaceAll method:

```
<a (?>[^h>]++|\Bh|h(?!ref\b))*href\s*=\s*["']?(http://)?([^\s"']++)["']?[^>]*>\s*+(?:http://)?\2\s*+<\/a\s*+>

replacement: $1$2
```

I wrote the pattern as a raw pattern thus, don't forget to escape double quotes and using double backslashes before using it.

The main interest of this pattern is that urls are compared without the substring `http://` to obtain more results.

Answer (score 0):

First, a reminder that regular expressions are not great for parsing XML/HTML: this HTML should parse out the same as what you've got, but it's really hard to write a regex for it:

```
<
a
foo="bar"
href="URL">


<nothing/>URL
</a
>
```

That's why we say "don't use regular expressions to parse XML!"

But it's often a great shortcut. What you're looking for is a *back-reference*:

```
<a href="([^"]+)">\1</a>
```

This will match when the quoted string and the contents of the a-element are the same.  The `\1` matches whatever was captured in group 1. You can also use named capturing groups if you like a little more documentation in your regular expressions.  See [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more options.